# Python, perplexity about "is" operator on integers

Tags: python-3.x

Could you explain me simply why `(3**2000 is 3**2000)` is evaluated as `False`?

Comment: Why do you think it should be `True`? Are the two results the *same object*? Or are they two different objects with the *same value*?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters:
Thank you for your quick answer but how to explain that (3**2 is 3**2) is evaluated as True?

Comment: See the linked duplicate. `3 ** 2` is `9`, which is an interned number. That small numbers are interned (cached) is an optimisation.